# Jekyll custom theme not working on Github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a jekyll site that I want to deploy as github-pages. It works fine standalone but fails to build within github-pages with the include error from _index.html. I don't even have an _include directory. I am using the minimal-mistakes theme. I have slimmed down my site to the bare bones it can be found at https://github.com/laredo/mm-jekyll

The exact error is: A file was included in `index.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory.

https://github.com/laredo/mm-jekyll/blob/master/index.html

Looking for suggestions to successfully build the site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your _config.yml

- delete `theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll`
- add `remote_theme: mmistakes/minimal-mistakes`
- enable jekyll-include-cache in the plugins configuration

Plugins config is now :

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-include-cache
```

Comment: You also need to add the gem to the Gemfile : `gem 'jekyll-include-cache'` so it continues to work locally for your development.

Comment: Thanks for the response and editing of the post, question though - why edit the subject line? the Error string in the subject line will help more people find the issue

Comment: More details related to this answer can be found here: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/1937

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog based on Jekyll and Minimal Mistakes. It's already hosted in github-pages. I don't know how you started your project, but what worked to me was just clone the [minimal mistakes Github repository](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) and change the _config.yml.

Comment: Your _config.yml should uncomment the `remote_theme` line, how are you referring to that theme if not via that line?